# Как сделать вывод в строчку только 3 статьи, а остальные уже на другой php?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$i=0;
while($i<count($news)){
  if ($i++%3==0) {
     echo "<br />";//переход на другую строчку 
  }
  echo "<article>";
  echo '<div id="img_div">
  <img src="/images/'.$news[$i]["image"].'" >
  <p>'.$news[$i]['intro_text'].'</p>

  </div>';
  echo "</article>";             
}
```

при помощи цикла выводим 3 статьи в ряд , а потом делаем 3 статьи на след ряду и так далее...как этот переход осуществить ? думаю что при помощи if , но я чет туплю и не знаю что внутри  написать ..помогите, заранее спасибо

Comment: Это делается на CSS

Comment: ок , а как ?...реально туплю сегодня

Answer (score 0):

Это делается через CSS. Вариантов как это сделать множество.

> Можно использовать [Bootstrap (фреймворк)](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/).
>
> Можно использовать [CSS GRID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid)
>
> Можно написать на  чистом CSS

В таком случае ваш PHP будет вот таким:

```
<?php $i=0;

while($i<count($news)){ ?> 

 <article>
   <div id="img_div">
    <img src="/images/<?php echo $news[$i]["image"];?>" >
    <p><?php echo $news[$i]['intro_text']; ?></p>
   </div>
 </article>
         
<?php }
```

Например:

**Вариант 1**:

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
article {
    background-color: #444;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px 5px;
}
div#img_div {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <article>
   <div id="img_div">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random?gravity=center" title="Картинка с БД" >
    <p>Произвольный текст с БД</p>
   </div>
  </article>
  <article>
   <div id="img_div">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random?gravity=north" title="Картинка с БД" >
    <p>Произвольный текст с БД</p>
   </div>
  </article>
  <article>
   <div id="img_div">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random?gravity=east" title="Картинка с БД" >
    <p>Произвольный текст с БД</p>
   </div>
  </article>
  <article>
   <div id="img_div">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random?gravity=south" title="Картинка с БД" >
    <p>Произвольный текст с БД</p>
   </div>
  </article>
  <article>
   <div id="img_div">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random?gravity=west" title="Картинка с БД" >
    <p>Произвольный текст с БД</p>
   </div>
  </article>
  <article>
   <div id="img_div">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random?gravity=center" title="Картинка с БД" >
    <p>Произвольный текст с БД</p>
   </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

**Вариант 2**:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Create four equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 300px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Колонка 1</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Колонка 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
    <h2>Колонка 3</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <h2>Колонка 4</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: я попробовал эти способы соединить с моим кодом ... он не меняет нечего. как было в строчку так и есть

Comment: Удалите свои стили, добавьте стили CSS с ответа. Посмотрите структуру HTML вывода вашего когда, совпадает ли она с той и что в ответе

Comment: ok. спасибо за помощь. попробуем

Comment: Если код работает тут но не работает у вас, значит дело в вас.  Проанализируйте стили css, может в вашем коде прописано чтобы блоки выводились только в строку.

Comment: Если есть возможность выложите весь код или ссылку на ресурс

Comment: это кусочек так как проект большой ( ну по моим меркам) так что трудновато всё кидать 

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1T_sAGoR0CBJhBhU6nOwbG3XlCyV7xpge

Comment: @СаскеУчиха вообще все не так

Comment: Посмотрите на мой код и на свой код. Если не увидите разницы, отвернитесь и посмотрите еще раз. И так до тех пор пока не сделаете правильно как в ответе.

Comment: сделал ))))https://drive.google.com/open?id=1T_sAGoR0CBJhBhU6nOwbG3XlCyV7xpge
переместил if чуть ниже

Comment: @СаскеУчиха опять не верно, вообще не туда смотрите, ну да ладно.  Обновил ответ посмотрите на php код

Comment: понял ...спасибо Вам большое , что уделили время такому дауну )))

Comment: @СаскеУчиха Если ответ вам помог и верный отметьте его галочкой и поставьте + (стрелка вверх)    :)